# The map displayed using mapbox navigation style comes up but with a 404 in the console

Tags: http-status-code-404, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am using the navigation-night-v1 or navigation-day-v1 both of them appears to come up with 404 not found [on this page](https://demo01.inmo.io/PropiedadDetalles.aspx?Pr_Id=5611) for the following https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-incidents-v1/14/4867/9996.vector.pbf?sku=101wtyR1vuXrQ&access_token=mykeyhere

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'mykey';  
var map = new mapboxgl.Map
(
{
container: 'map-canvas',  
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/navigation-night-v1',  
center: [ -73.05273, -36.81938],  
zoom: 14 
}
);  

var el = document.createElement('div'); 
el.className = 'marker32'; 
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el)  
.setLngLat([ -73.05273, -36.81938])  
.addTo(map);
```